# Why doesn't this use of the pipe operator work?

Tags: bash, pipe

I normally use `pidof` to get the pid of a process, and `KILL -SIGTERM <pid>` to terminate it.

The pipe should give the output of one command as an input to another.

So why doesn't the following command work?

```
pidof firefox | kill -SIGTERM
```

Comment: Also related:  [Where are command line arguments (e.g., 'some.text') actually passed to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43489/80216) (“STDIN and the program command ( including arguments ) are completely different things.”) and [Bash function that accepts input from parameter or pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/301426/80216).

Comment: @muru it actually did! Those answers + the accepted one gave me a clear understanding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The pipe should give the output of one command as an input to another.

That's correct, but `kill` doesn't take any input on standard input. Instead you need to provide it as a command line argument:

```
kill -SIGTERM "$(pidof firefox)"
```

or:

```
pidof firefox | xargs kill
```

`$(` is command expansion inside the shell, whereas `xargs` is external.

However, these approaches have a number of corner cases, like what to do if there are multiple pids, no pids, etc -- this is why pkill exists:

```
pkill -TERM firefox
```

Comment: What's the difference between an input and a parameter here? Aren't they both just text that whatever the implementation of the command is will simply interpret differently?

Comment: "Input" here is [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) -- the data passed on file descriptor 0 to the process. A parameter is a part of the command line arguments passed to `execve`. You can think of a pipe as being something like a file that can't be seeked, but command line arguments are simply metadata related to the process in question.

Comment: Hm, which of them are the ones you can access through `argv` in a C program?

Comment: `argv` is arguments (`argv` means "argument vector"). In C, stdin is in the form of a file, so you use functions like `read` to access it instead.

Comment: This answer properly addresses the core issue of the question and OP's misconception, hence +1. STDIN and positional parameters are very different things and serve very different purposes - that's what needs to be emphasized.

Comment: My misunderstanding comes from the fact that, from the point of view of bash commands, both are passed as additional strings after the command itself. If I was writing C code of a program that can be used by command line, how would I "take an input on stdin" instead of just parameters on a command line? And how does bash differentiate between those?

Comment: When you pass a file name as an argument, the code has to explicitly open the file to read the contents (and file may or may not exist). If its the standard input, the file exists and is already opened...

Comment: @memememe you would read from `stdin` like it was a file.

Answer (score 1):

Better run:

```
 kill $(pidof firefox)
```

or

```
pkill firefox
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll use this one from now on. But why doesn't my version work? Is there anything wrong in my understanding of the pipe operator?

Comment: Sure, check `xargs`

Answer (score 0):

Just for diversity's sake: How about running:

```
kill -SIGTERM "$(pgrep -f firefox)"
```

Unsure about case-insensitivity:

```
kill -SIGTERM "$(pgrep -fi FirEfox)"
```

Multiple process running with same name, and want to kill the first one:

```
kill -SIGTERM "$(pgrep -f firefox | head -1)"
```

Info about my `pgrep`

```
$ pgrep -V
pgrep (proctools 0.4pre1) http://proctools.sourceforge.net
```